# Debug shows nginx try_files ignores a file that actually exists

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to build a location block that serves files from the `/tmp` directory, but only ones that do not end with a `.txt` extension.

For now I have this :

```
                location ~^\/temporary(?!.*\.txt$)(.*)$ {
                        root /tmp;
                        try_files $1 =404;
                }
```

The problem is I only get 404s, even though the file I'm asking for exists. I used a little debug to make sure of that, here's the debug dump for the "/temporary/test.html" URI:

```
022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 http script capture: "/test.html"                                                                                                     
2022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 trying to use file: "/test.html" "/tmp/test.html"                                                                                     
2022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 trying to use file: "=404" "/tmp=404"                                                                                                 
2022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/temporary/test.html?" a:1, c:1                                                                          
2022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 http special response: 404, "/temporary/test.html?"                                                                                   
2022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 http set discard body
2022/07/17 19:53:42 [debug] 6408#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

As you can see the server actually tried to read the `/tmp/test.html` file, so the path crafting has worked.

Also the file exists and is readable as shown with this command :

```
sudo -u nobody stat /tmp/test.html
  File: /tmp/test.html
  Size: 15              Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d      Inode: 2097220     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    nobody)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2022-07-17 19:26:19.701542983 +0300
Modify: 2022-07-17 19:53:17.923305174 +0300
Change: 2022-07-17 19:53:17.923305174 +0300
 Birth: 2022-07-17 19:26:19.701542983 +0300
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently the `/tmp` directory was the origin of the problem. When I tried another directory everything worked as expected for some reason.